# Querying subcollections in Firestore using Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to take all records from sub collection in Firestore.

Below is my table structure.

[image: Database screenshot attached]

Restaurants (Main table) --> RestaurantID (document) --> Reviews(Collection) --> ReviewID (document) --> multiple review details with their own uniqueID and will also have reviewDate field.

What I am trying to achieve is I want to list all reviews written on particular date.

If I pass `RestaurantID` then I am getting records but how to get all records without passing `RestaurantID`?

Is this possible to achieve in my current table structure? Or must I change it?

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: i have added screenshot of database

Comment: `ra2cee8...` is the id of a single restaurant? And you want to get records not from a single restaurant but from all, right? `Reviews` subcollection is the same under each restaurant?

Comment: Yes yes, ra2cee8... is the id of a single restaurant , i want to get all restaurant records and Reviews subcollection is the same under each restaurant.

Comment: Use [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all reviews for all restaurants, you can use a so-called [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) ([Flutter](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Firestore/collectionGroup.html)).

This type of query gets documents from all collections with a given name, so in your case `Reviews`.